# TERADATA REGEXP_SUBSTR Get string between two values

Tags: sql, regex, teradata

I am fairly new to teradata, but I was trying to understand how to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`

For example I have the following cell value = `ABCD^1234567890^1`

How can I extract `1234567890`

What I attempted to do is the following:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(x, '(?<=^).*?(?=^)')
```

But this didnt seem to work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Should be `REGEXP_SUBSTR(x, '\^([^^]*)\^', 1)` or similar. In case single backslashes do not work, double them.

Comment: If you're using `teradata` why is this also tagged `mysql` and `sql-server`? Those are both (very) different products. Please don't tag-spam.

Comment: The `^` has special meaning in regex so needs to be escaped in lookbehind/lookahead. Other than that, your pattern should work.

Comment: A bit more efficient avoiding the `.` wildcard: `REGEXP_SUBSTR(x, '(?<=\^)[^^]*')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might (or might not) be possible to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` to handle this, but you would need to use a capture group.  An alternative here would be to do a regex replacement instead:

```sql
SELECT x, REGEXP_REPLACE(x, '^.*?\^|\^.*$', '') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

The regex pattern used here matches:

- `^.*?\^` everything from the start to the *first* `^`
- `|` OR
- `\^.*$` everything from the second `^` to the end

We then replace with empty string to remove the content being matched.